# Derivative of rational function can be bounded by the rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, rational-functions

I'm studying something about singular value and I came across a problem.

1. Matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & 1 \\ 0 & a \end{bmatrix}$ is a Jordan matrix with $a>1$.
2. For an integer $k$, let $r(z) = p(z)/q(z)$ is an irreducible rational function on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials of degree $k$, and $p$ and $q$ are not zero on $\mathbb{R}$.

**My problem is finding a positive number $K$ (possibly depend on $k$) such that
\begin{equation}
\|r(A)\|_2 \leq K \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |r(x)|.
\end{equation}**

Now I have get that
\begin{equation}
r(A) = \begin{bmatrix}
r(a) & r'(a) \\ 0 & r(a)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and $\|r(A)\|_2 \leq \sqrt{2}\|r(A)\|_1 = \sqrt{2}(|r(a)| + |r'(a)|)$. Thus I guess that there may exist a positive number $K_1$ (possibly depend on $k$) such that
\begin{equation}
|r'(a)| \leq K_1 \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |r(x)|.
\end{equation}
However, I don't know how to prove or disprove this conjecture. If anyone knows how to do this, I'll thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I think there is no positive number $K_1$(possibly depend on $k$) such that
\begin{equation}
|r'(a)| \leq K_1 \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |r(x)|.
\end{equation}

For example, let $r(z) := \frac{z-a}{z-a+t \mathbf{i}}$, where $t > 0$ is a real number, and $\mathbf{i} = \sqrt{-1} $. Then it is easy to get that
\begin{equation}
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |r(x)| = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} |r(x)| = 1.
\end{equation}
However, $r'(z) = \frac{t\mathbf{i}}{(z-a+t \mathbf{i})^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, this means that
\begin{equation}
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |r'(x)| =  |r'(a)| = \frac{1}{t} = \frac{1}{t}\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |r(x)|.
\end{equation}
If let $t \rightarrow 0_{+}$, then it implies that
\begin{equation}
\frac{|r'(a)|}{\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |r(x)|} \rightarrow +\infty.
\end{equation}